# How to save my time with Vim and Behat, with a shortcut?

Tags: vim, behat

I am working with Vim and Behat. When I add new Scenario, or when a scenario fails, I type this command inside vim

```
:!bin/behat %:42
```

When I have the cursor inside a Scenario of a feature, is possible to create a shortcut, to run behat exactly for this Scenario?

```
42        Scenario: run behat scenario with shortcut
43            Given my cursor is on a scenario
44            Then I can run behat just for this one
45            And save my time
```

Comment: Do you mean you just want to run `Scenario: run behat scenario with shortcut` in the feature?

Comment: Yes, ... I want to run just that scenario

Answer (score 0):

When I use symfony I can do it like:

```
bin/behat --profile=your_profile_name YourFeatureFileName.feature:42
```

So only the scenario which is on line 42 runs.

Comment: You might be interested in [this](http://knplabs.com/en/blog/vim-behat) and [this](https://github.com/tpope/vim-cucumber)

Comment: I just want to alert you that ":!bin/behat %:42: is the same of your "bin/behat --profile=your_profile_name YourFeatureFileName.feature:42"